# When `my_variable IN (<long_array_of_items>)` is fast in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I find my self sometimes needing to select many items of different tables based on a list of id's or other variables. Given that this list can contain thousands of elements, it is important for me that the filter does not become a n*m query. I have experienced that under some circumstances postgres makes fast lookups and sometimes not, for example if I filter by primary key. When it made slow filtering I typically solved it by creating an `IN` query table and join it with the table to make the filter.

But now I'm back at the problem again and I really want to hear if somebody can help me build some intuition for when I should assume that lookup is used and when a hash table is used.

At my current work we are using postgres 15, but most of my experience is from postgres 10, so there might be some bad habits from older versions.

Comment: Why assume if you can [`explain analyze verbose`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html). It's hard to comment on why `IN` *worked so well* without seeing examples of what it replaced and how.

Comment: Please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, the SQL statement that is slow and the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for this statements. All in plain text, as an update of the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v14 introduced an optimization (commit 50e17ad281b8d1c1b) to use a hash table for large IN-lists rather than doing a linear search over the IN-list for each candidate row.  So since then, you shouldn't get O(n*m) behavior.  There might be corner cases, like if the IN-list is computed dynamically or if the types are not fully compatible. Nothing in the query plan indicates that this optimization is being done (other than the lowered cost estimate).

Even before v14, if the column being tested was indexed then it could hop on the index once for each member of the list and so avoid the O(n*m) behavior that way.  Behind the scenes this is a loop, but in the query plan it is just presented as an index scan with the index condition being `Index Cond: (col1 = ANY('{...`

Comment: Thank you very much. This knowledge made it much simpler for me to solve these types of problems and where exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I was using `column = ANY (VALUES (...), ...)` at some point instead of making N batch requests with `IN` because it was faster (basically it creates a temp table and then joins with it) but looks like in Postgres 15 it's not a case and regular `IN` even with 2000 values works 2x faster than value list filter. (But maybe at some N it's still faster that `IN`)

Having `sku_test` table setup as

```sql
CREATE TABLE sku_test (
    code integer PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and with around 22k records

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM sku_test
WHERE code IN (64309, 64310, ...);
```

results in

```
Seq Scan on sku_test  (cost=5.00..450.03 rows=2000 width=4) (actual time=0.343..13.693 rows=2000 loops=1)
  Filter: (code = ANY ('{64309, 64310, ...}'::integer[]))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 20869
Planning Time: 7.619 ms
Execution Time: 14.275 ms
```

and

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM sku_test
WHERE code = ANY(VALUES (64309), (64310), ...);
```

results in

```
Hash Semi Join  (cost=50.00..462.97 rows=2000 width=4) (actual time=4.169..28.998 rows=2000 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (sku_test.code = "*VALUES*".column1)
  ->  Seq Scan on sku_test  (cost=0.00..330.69 rows=22869 width=4) (actual time=0.055..10.293 rows=22869 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=25.00..25.00 rows=2000 width=4) (actual time=4.033..4.040 rows=2000 loops=1)
        Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 87kB
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=2000 width=4) (actual time=0.010..2.344 rows=2000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 6.780 ms
Execution Time: 29.746 ms
```

And I see similar results on production database with live table and index on filtering column.

But again, it's always better to measure by yourself.

upd: as example for @FrankHeikens reply here is an example for 1M table with text column and unique index on it, and ~10k filter

```sql
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT round(random() * 1e12)::TEXT AS code FROM pg_catalog.generate_series(1, 1e6);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX itest ON test(code);
```

`IN`

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT code FROM test
WHERE code IN (
'801642034794',
'579842212309',
...
);
```

results in

```
Gather  (cost=1024.89..13676.39 rows=9955 width=12) (actual time=81.602..405.323 rows=9955 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=24.89..11680.89 rows=4148 width=12) (actual time=5.277..258.142 rows=3318 loops=3)
        Filter: (code = ANY ('{801642034794,579842212309, ...}'::text[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 330015
Planning Time: 33.708 ms
Execution Time: 408.542 ms
```

and using `VALUES`

```
Gather  (cost=1248.88..12956.94 rows=9955 width=12) (actual time=147.406..656.538 rows=9955 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=248.88..10961.44 rows=4148 width=12) (actual time=28.546..450.157 rows=3318 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (test.code = "*VALUES*".column1)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..9572.67 rows=416667 width=12) (actual time=1.610..164.941 rows=333333 loops=3)
        ->  Hash  (cost=124.44..124.44 rows=9955 width=32) (actual time=24.629..24.658 rows=9955 loops=3)
              Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 565kB
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..124.44 rows=9955 width=32) (actual time=0.157..12.857 rows=9955 loops=3)
Planning Time: 30.204 ms
Execution Time: 659.705 ms
```

Comment: 22k records with a single 4 byte value, is next to nothing.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'll add example with 1M rows table and 10k in filter if that makes a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

Why assume if you can [`explain analyze verbose`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html). It's hard to comment on why `IN` *worked so well* without seeing examples of what it replaced and how.

Even having good enough intuition to trust it, you're still better off if you *trust, but verify*. Server config, index setup, table size, traffic and how often it's `vacuum analyze`d can all have impact on what the planner comes up with, and it can change version to version. All human intuition in this context is doomed to be unreliable and get quickly outdated.

That being said, [here are some 1M-row tests at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZuzl6uH), here are some  [comparisons of `in`, `any`, `exists`, `join` behaviour](https://www.percona.com/blog/sql-optimizations-in-postgresql-in-vs-exists-vs-any-all-vs-join/), here's [some more, more visual](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/rise-of-the-anti-join).